# Print the collatz sequence of a positive int, n, one value per line stoping at 1 using python

Tags: python, int, collatz

I've done:

```
def collatz(n):
    seq = n
    if n == 1:
        n = n
    while n > 1:
       if n % 2 == 0:
           n = n // 2
       else:
           n = 3 * n + 1
    print(seq)
```

The corrct output for calling this function, while n = 10:

```
collatz(10)
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

But the only number printed is n itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are only printing `seq` which was set to `n` at start of the function, after the while loop has executed. Hence you only get the value printed once.

You should print the value inside the `while` loop as well as at start (for the first `10` print). Example -

```
def collatz(n):
    print(n)
    while n > 1:
       if n % 2 == 0:
           n = n // 2
       else:
           n = 3 * n + 1
       print(n)
```

Demo -

```
>>> def collatz(n):
...     print(n)
...     while n > 1:
...        if n % 2 == 0:
...            n = n // 2
...        else:
...            n = 3 * n + 1
...        print(n)
...
>>> collatz(10)
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Comment: Thank you I solved it right when I saw your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- You need to print once for every step within your loop. Your print statement is *outside* your while loop hence it only fires once.
- Additionally, you want to print the value that is changing `n` not `seq` which never chances in this function.
- On that note, you don't even need `seq` as you never use it!
- The two lines `if n == 1: n = n` don't do anything. Even if `n==1`, setting n to itself doesn't change the value.